# Merge indexed array of associative arrays and sum the values of recurring keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge, array-sum

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [GB] => 20827
        [US] => 73
        [ES] => 23
        [AU] => 15
        [DE] => 12
        [MY] => 4
        [QA] => 1
        [VN] => 1
        [SK] => 1
        [FJ] => 1
        [ME] => 1
        [TR] => 1
        [LV] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [GB] => 15070
        [US] => 3920
        [IE] => 1711
        [PH] => 1071
        [MT] => 578
        [AU] => 423
        [HR] => 241
        [ZA] => 210
        [FR] => 139
    )
)
```

I want to create a new array with all of the associative elements in each array of the multidimensional array and sum the values of duplicated keys.

Desired result from sample input:

```
array (
  'GB' => 35897,
  'US' => 3993,
  'ES' => 23,
  'AU' => 438,
  'DE' => 12,
  'MY' => 4,
  'QA' => 1,
  'VN' => 1,
  'SK' => 1,
  'FJ' => 1,
  'ME' => 1,
  'TR' => 1,
  'LV' => 1,
  'IE' => 1711,
  'PH' => 1071,
  'MT' => 578,
  'HR' => 241,
  'ZA' => 210,
  'FR' => 139,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through each of the sub-arrays, and then loop through the key/value pairs. Add them up in a `$final` array:

```
$final = [];
foreach($masterArray as $subArray) {
    foreach($subArray AS $key => $value) {
        $final[$key] = isset($final[$key])
            ? $final[$key] + $value
            : $value;
    }
}
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/6XBbD

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like

```
$array = count($array1) > count($array2) ? $array1 : $array2;
$otherArray = count($array1) > count($array2) ? $array2 : $array1;

array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key, $otherArray) {
    $value = $value + (isset($otherArray[$key]) ? $otherArray[$key] : 0);
}, $otherArray);
```

Comment: The multidimensional array can be filled with more than 2 other arrays of data. Im trying to merge them all into one.

Comment: then process them one by one using the method above.

Answer (score 0):

You can fast track this task by "shifting" the first row of data off of the input array and pushing the associative elements directly into the output array.  This removes the need to execute any conditional operations on the first row which will improve efficiency.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pXUkc))

```
$result = array_shift($array);
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = ($result[$key] ?? 0) + $value;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Alterative with `array_reduce()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oH3SQ))

```
$result = array_shift($array);
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $array,
        function($result, $row) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                $result[$key] = ($result[$key] ?? 0) + $value;
            }
            return $result;
        },
        $result
    )
);
```

---

Alternative with `array_merge_recursive()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jaIPL))

```
$result = array_shift($array);
array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function($value, $key) use(&$result) {
        $result[$key] = ($result[$key] ?? 0) + $value;
    }
);
var_export($result);
```

As a side effect of using `array_shift()`, if the input array is empty, then the output of all snippets above will be `null` instead of an empty array. If this is a deal-breaker for your project, then replace `array_shift()` with an empty array -- [Demo](https://3v4l.org/PR7Ln).