# how to ommit array from multidimensional array based on their values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an input array:

```
 Array(
        Array(
            [vehicle] => BUS NO.1
            [trip_name] => Trip00011
            [running_km] => 5000
        )
        Array(
            [vehicle] => BUS NO.2
            [trip_name] => Trip00021
            [running_km] => 2400
        )
        Array(
            [vehicle] => BUS NO.1
            [trip_name] => Trip00011
            [running_km] => 0
        )
        Array(
            [vehicle] => BUS NO.2
            [trip_name] => Trip00011
            [running_km] => 0
        )
        Array(
            [vehicle] => BUS NO.2
            [trip_name] => Trip00021
            [running_km] => 0
        )
    )
```

I need to change this array into:

```
Array(
    Array(
        [vehicle] => BUS NO.1
        [trip_name] => Trip00011
        [running_km] => 5000
    )
    Array(
        [vehicle] => BUS NO.2
        [trip_name] => Trip00021
        [running_km] => 2400
    )
    Array(
        [vehicle] => BUS NO.2
        [trip_name] => Trip00011
        [running_km] => 0
    )
)
```

Please look in to two arrays. I need to omit `running_km => 0` array based on the value present in `running_km` for same `vehicle` **and** same `trip_name`. Could you please help me to do this.

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. SO is _not_ a free coding service. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge multidimensional array with sum of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952317/merge-multidimensional-array-with-sum-of-values)

Comment: Doesn't my answer work for you @miya?

Answer (score 1):

If you loop the array you can build a compound array key. (Example: 'BUS NO.2 Trip00021').
And if the the running km is more then overwrite the item in the new array.

After the loop I do a array_values to remove the associative array keys to indexed array keys.

```
foreach($arr as $item){
    $key = $item['vehicle'] . $item['trip_name'];
    if(isset($new[$key])){
        if($item['running_km'] > $new[$key]['running_km']) $new[$key] = $item;
    }else{
        $new[$key] = $item;
    }

}
$new = array_values($new);

var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["vehicle"]=>
    string(8) "BUS NO.1"
    ["trip_name"]=>
    string(9) "Trip00011"
    ["running_km"]=>
    string(4) "5000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["vehicle"]=>
    string(8) "BUS NO.2"
    ["trip_name"]=>
    string(9) "Trip00021"
    ["running_km"]=>
    string(4) "2400"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["vehicle"]=>
    string(8) "BUS NO.2"
    ["trip_name"]=>
    string(9) "Trip00011"
    ["running_km"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/4qX7q